# Tab Bar Controller .. Item Title

Tags: ios, tabbar

i have 3 Items in my TabBar, and i will load a saved Title for this Items...

this works with this Code in ViewDidLoad..

```
  NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"char1_class"];
                NSString *charleveltitel = [defaults objectForKey:@"char1_class_level"];


                NSString *titel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", loadstring, charleveltitel];
                self.navigationItem.title =  titel ;


                [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(titel, @"comment")];
```

but... only when i click on the Bar Item... the code Starts in the ViewDidLoad...

i will load this for all Tabs by start the App...

Thanks Jürgen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, why not just set the title on the tab controllers in the storyboards?

*or*

You can also set this in your appDelegate.m file for each view controller that is in your tab controller by doing this:

```
[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:<index of the controller you want to change>] setTitle:@"The Title"];
```